# Do xml statements that center take actionbars into account?

Tags: android

Statements such as **android:layout_centerInParent="true"**, does it center by taking the actionbar into account? Because when I use two backgrounds both of the same height that meet in the middle using a fake view that is centered in the parent, the top baclground loooks squished and I think it might be because of the action bar. Hopefully this picture can show what I mean...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the action bar is placed above the rest of your layout. If you want it to be drawn in front of your layout you have to enable overlay mode. Having that in mind, most probably the vertical center of your layout is the center of the area below the action bar (e.g. the leftmost item in your diagram)

You can find more info about the overlay mode at the end of the [Removing the action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing) section of the [ActionBar dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).